# How would I send a post request for a google form AM / PM button?

Tags: java, android, google-forms, okhttp

[GOOGLE FORM AM/PM OPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4DBV.png)

A part of my program's task is to allow the user to enter in the times in the android application, and I have no clue how to do this post request without knowing the ENTRY or form input.

I read a bunch of documentation and figured it out. :)